# c# WPF get assemblyInfo.cs data

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-assembly

I want to read the Copyright and other attributes from the `assemblyInfo.cs` file.
The problem is, that I can't find anything in the web.

My AssemblyInfo.cs file:

```
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©Pascal Hurni  2016")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("Crypto AG")]
```

Now I want to get these Data from an other Window like:

```
string copyright = Something
```

Comment: Okay, so have you tried using `Assembly.GetCustomAttributes()`?

Comment: The problem is, that there is no `Assembly.Something` in my intellisense

Comment: Well you need to call it *on* an `Assembly`, yes. Normally the easiest way to get that is using `typeof(SomeTypeInYourAssembly).Assembly`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Assembly.GetCustomAttributes()` it's in `System.Reflection`